# if a column contains a specific text, copy column A matched to my cell text using VBA

Tags: vba

If column C in Sheet2 contains the string "ciao", then copy to column D, the column A matched to that cell.

To be more specific, here an example:

```
    col A:         
    row1: 1        
    row2: 2        
    row3: 3        
    row4: 4        

    col C:        
    row1: one        
    row2: ciao        
    row3: three        
    row4: ciao        

    col D:  (what I want)      
    row1:        
    row2: 2        
    row3:        
    row4: 4
```

Here is my code that copying entire row. But I want to copy only column A matched:

```
   Dim bottomC As Integer
   bottomC = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   Dim c As Range
   For Each c In Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C1:C" & bottomC)
       If c.Value = "ciao" Then
           c.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
       End If
    next c
```

Who can help me?

Comment: why do you use .EntireRow if you just want the cell that you've got before that .(of EntireRow) the 'c' contains the value you want to copy.

Comment: @Goosebumbs: if I use 'c.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)', in column D nothing happens. D column is empty

Comment: you could try adding the value of 'c' to a variable and get the row of 'c' and that add that variable to '"D" & (row index of c)'

Comment: I am setting up an answer ;)

Comment: how to het the row of c? this is my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This goes through every instance of C and if c matches "Ciao" it copys the value of the cell 2 to the left (Column A) to the cell one to the right (column D)

You should also use more descriptive variable names & declare all your variable at the start of the module - This makes it a lot easier to spot any errors.

I would write this code as follows:

```
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim Myrange As Range

   lastrow = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   For Each Myrange In Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C1:C" & lastrow)
       If Myrange = "ciao" Then Myrange.Offset(0, 1) = Myrange.Offset(0, -2)

    Next Myrange
```

Comment: also a good solution. Only you should end your if to prevent errors.

Comment: As the IF statement is a single line there is no need for end if.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim bottomC As Integer
bottomC = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim cRow As Long

Dim c As Range
For Each c In Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C1:C" & bottomC)
    If c.Value = "ciao" Then
        cRow = c.Row
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & cRow).Value = c.Offset(, -2).Value
    End If
next c
```

That should work.

EDIT: I tested the c.Row and it worked.